# Unable to change user password in MySQL 8.0.34 with plugin mysql_native_password

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-22.04

I am unable to change the user password in `MySQL 8.0.34` with plugin `mysql_native_password` and I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

```
sandeep@sandeep-Inspiron-3493:~$ mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use mysql
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> select user,plugin from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------------------+
| user             | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| debian-sys-maint | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.infoschema | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.session    | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.sys        | caching_sha2_password |
| root             | mysql_native_password |
| sandeep          | mysql_native_password |
+------------------+-----------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER USER 'sandeep'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Whatever35!';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'sandeep'@'localhost'
```

Comment: I think I managed to fix it. Needed to login to MySQL as sudo `sudo mysql -u root; use mysql; select user, plugin from mysql.user; ALTER USER 'sandeep'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new_password'; flush privileges;`